# How can I create a Partial Dependence plot for a categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning, random-forest, categorical-data

I am working with the r-package randomForest and have successfully made a random forest model and an importance plot. I am working with a dichotomous response and several categorical predictors.

However, I can't figure out how to make partial dependence plots for my categorical variables. I have tried using the randomForest command partialPLot. But I get the following error:

```
> partialPlot(rf.5, rf.train.1, religion)
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

.

So my question is: Can anyone explain in a simple way how you would make a random forest partial dependence plot for a categorical variable?

This is the kind of plot I want to make: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235667/partial-dependence-plot-interpretation-for-categorical-variables

Would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to use `partialPlot` for a categorical explanatory variable. Check if the classes of the inputs of your `partialPlot` are the same of this example. 
 I hope this can help you.
The dataset `df` has a binary independent variable `x4` and a binary response variable `y`:

```
df <- data.frame(iris[,1:3], x4=factor(iris$Petal.Width>1.5), 
                         y=factor(iris$Species=="virginica"))
str(df)

######################
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ x4          : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ y           : Factor w/ 2 levels "FALSE","TRUE": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Here is the partial plot for `x4`:

```
library(randomForest)
RF <- randomForest(y~., data=df)

partialPlot(x=RF, pred.data=df, x.var=x4, which.class="TRUE")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! But when I try what you did I get the following error: 
`> partialPlot(x=rf.5, pred.data=rf.train.1, x.var=rel, which.class="4")
Error in partialPlot.randomForest(x = rf.5, pred.data = rf.train.1, x.var = rel,  : 4is not one of the class labels.`

But "4" is definetly one of the level labels, so what is happening? 

If i remove "which.class=", I get the following error: 
`> partialPlot(x=rf.5, pred.data=rf.train.1, x.var=rel)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Do you know why this happens?  
Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the result of `str(rf.train.1)` ?

Comment: Sure! `> str(rf.train.1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 47102 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ rel    : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 10 3 6 6 6 8 6 8 5 ...
 $ relprac:Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:47102] 4 3 2 2 3 2 4 3 3 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:12] -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "Missing" "Never" "A few times a year" "About once a month" ...`

Comment: `which.class` must be one of the class of the outcome, not of the independent variable.

Comment: Okay, now I have changed it to a class of the outcome variable. I now get this error:                `partialPlot(x=rf.5, pred.data=rf.train.1, x.var=rel, which.class= "1")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: Didn't work. "A few times a year" is not one of the class labels of the outcome. This is the outcome: `str(rf.label)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`

Comment: OK, choose one of the two categories

Comment: I did that and got: `partialPlot(x=rf.5, pred.data=rf.train.1, x.var=rel, which.class= "1") Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`
Do you know what this is? 
Really appreciating your help by the way.

Comment: Try with `partialPlot(x=rf.5, pred.data=as.data.frame(rf.train.1), x.var=rel, which.class="1")`. I added a `as.data.frame`

Comment: I did. It says that the vote was recorded but that votes from people with under 15 rep will not be displayed... I also "checked" your answer and that gets displayed.

Comment: What does the y-axis represent in the plot ?

Answer (score 1):

The [plotmo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotmo/index.html) R package will plot partial dependencies for all variables and pairs of variables (bivariate dependencies) for "any" model,
including those with categorical variables and responses.

For a brief plotmo example, see
[Bivariate partial dependence with randomForest in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101629/bivariate-partial-dependence-with-randomforest-in-r).